# Service method not called in controller

Tags: java, spring, junit

**My controller class:**

```java
package some.pkg.controller;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api", produces="application/json")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private IntSequenceFilter sequenceFilter;

    @PostMapping("/odd")
    public FilteredSequence filterOdd(@RequestBody SequenceRequest sequenceRequest) {
        List<Integer> filteredSequence = sequenceFilter.process(sequenceRequest.getData());
        return new FilteredSequence(filteredSequence);
    }
}
```

**My service class:**

```java
package some.pkg.service;

@Service
public class IntSequenceFilter {
    // ... Some code ... 
}
```

This is my **test:**

```java
package some.pkg.controller    

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private IntSequenceFilter sequenceFilter;

    @Test
    public void testFilter() throws Exception {
        MvcResult response = mockMvc.perform(
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/odd")
                        .content("{\"data\":\"1;2;3;-1;-2;-3\"}")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andReturn();

        // ... Some assertions ...
    }
}
```

When i run test, **sequenceFilter.process()** not called inside controller's **filterOdd** method. Can someone please help me to figure it out what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are saying `sequenceFilter.process()` is not getting called by checking log statements inside the process() method.

It's a Mock, you need to mock the behavior as below

```
  Mockito.when (sequenceFilter.process (Mockito.any ())).thenReturn (sequences);
```

If you want to call actual service implementation,use `Spy`

Replace

```
@MockBean
private IntSequenceFilter sequenceFilter;
```

with

```
@SpyBean
private IntSequenceFilter sequenceFilter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the below setup method as it setups the controller with the mocks.

```
@InjectMocks
private MyController myController;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.setMockMvc(MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).build());
    // set return values from the mocked service
    when(sequenceFilter.process(...).thenReturn(...);
}
```